# What am I implementing wrong?

Tags: java

I am trying to get my button to display a dialog box. When clicking, it does nothing.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHelloWorld);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dialog.setTitle("Made by");
                dialog.setMessage("Justin Rhinehart\nMGMS | APM\n5/4/2021");
                dialog.setPositiveButton(" OK ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id ) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am new to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind the click in the `onCreate` method (and this is what you probably want):

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHelloWorld);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Made by");
        dialog.setMessage("Justin Rhinehart\nMGMS | APM\n5/4/2021");
        dialog.setPositiveButton(" OK ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id ) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

But code can work in many different ways... for example in the`onCreate` function you could just have done `this.onClick(null)` and probably your code might have worked also, but I would not recommend it, because there will be no sense at that point to the `implements View.OnClickListener`

Comment: Thank you!! All of the examples I was seeing and following along with had the set button under the onClick.

Comment: you are probably getting pieces of code from different sources, and so you ending up with something without much sense... try to stick with one tutorial/guide and follow that

Comment: and don't take everything as gold, there might be errors also on the tutorials (and if the answer solved the question, feel free to mark it as correct)